# Return & Call Variables Outside Functions in Python... What's Wrong here?

Tags: python, validation, try-catch

I hate asking duplicate questions, but I have been researching and working on this program all day without much luck. It's supposed to take a temperature of water in Cel. or Far., and an altitude in Feet or Meters, and  tell you whether at the given altitude, the water is either in liquid, gas, or solid form (not factoring in atmospheric pressure, I am just trying to get a rough estimate based on the altitude). The rules of thumb is that water will boil at ~1 degree lower than 100 degrees C. for every 300 meters (or 1000 feet) above sea-level.

I managed to find a couple ways to make it return a roughly correct number. The next step is adding error checking to the program. I tried a 'try' clause, but it does not catch the errors, and for the life of me I cannot figure out why.

**Edit**

I tried this a different way, and it works, catching the errors, except for one odd problem. When entering the input in both functions inpALT() and inpTEMP, it asks me to enter the input twice, and than returns the correct values... :

```
def inpALT():
    alt = str(input("Enter altitude above altlevel, format 100M/F :"))
    if re.match(r'[0-9]*[mMfF]$', alt):
        return alt
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid Format")     

def inpTEMP():
    temp = str(input("Tempurature in format 70C/F :"))
    if re.match(r'[0-9]*[cCfF]$', temp):
    return temp
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid Format")


while True:
    try:
        inpALT()
        break
    except ValueError:("Invalid Format")      

while True:
    try:
        inpTEMP()
        break
    except ValueError:("Invalid Format")

temp = inpTEMP()
alt = inpALT()

---- snip ----
```

However, it only does so after I have to enter the data *twice*:

> Enter altitude above altlevel, format 100M/F :100F
>
> Enter Temperature in format 70C/F :100F
>
> Enter Tempurature in format 70C/F :100F
>
> Enter altitude above altlevel, format 100M/F :100F

Why does it do that...?

Comment: To capture the return value from a function, you have to assign it to a variable like this: `temp = inF()`. The returned value will afterwards be stored in the `temp` variable.

Comment: Additionally, the matching of your regular expressions is never performed because you always return before the line is executed.

Comment: I still am a little lost-- would you please explain what you mean regarding the regex's not being matched?

Comment: That's because of the way the "return" keyword works. It immediately returns the given value and jumps to the location where the function is called, "replacing" the function call with the returned value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a summary from the help you got in the comments. I provide you a corrected code for your specific problem. I've commented it, so I hope it helps a lot by reading and implementing it by yourself.

I tried to give you an idea with restructering your code inside the `while loop`. I do not recommend the provided code, but that's not the point here. I wanted not to break your coding style too much. And I concentrated on the second code you provided. For me it's not clear where I have to go exactly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""corrected version with more PEP8 included."""

import re
import sys  # just for exit the script. There are multiple other ways.

# the assignments will be done later, no need for that here.
# alt = ""
# temp = ""


# readable names are better than cryptic ones
def get_altitude():
    alt = str(input("Enter altitude above sealevel, format 100M/F: "))

    # after `return` code will not be executed. You have to do it before the
    # return statement as mentioned by jojonas. Maybe you will also allow a
    # minus at the beginning and disallow no numbers (+ instead of *)?
    if not re.match(r'[0-9]*[mMfF]$', alt):
        raise ValueError

    return alt


# readable names are better than cryptic ones
def get_temperature():
    temp = str(input("Tempurature in format 70C/F: "))

    # the same here with the return statement
    if not re.match(r'[0-9]*[cCfF]$', temp):
        raise ValueError

    return temp


# The while loop stands for: do it forever. Maybe this is not what you want?!
# The user has to give a wrong input format (then sys.exit is your friend as
# one example of stopping the script or the user has to manually stop the
# script (STRG+C) or something like that. There are better ways.
while True:
    try:
        # you need to assign the returned values to a variable as mentioned
        # by jojonas already. Here is the way of doing it.
        alt = get_altitude()
        temp = get_temperature()

    # slight change in catching the error
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid input format!')
        sys.exit(1)

    # finally will be done after exception occured! If you don't use
    # sys.exit (as I did as a fast hack not to totally disorder your
    # program), you have to be careful about this solution.
    finally:
        t = ''.join(x for x in temp if x.isdigit())
        a = ''.join(x for x in alt if x.isdigit())

        t = int(t)
        a = int(a)

        if "F" in temp:
            # just another way of expressing the same:
            t -= 32 / 1.8

        if "F" in alt:
            # just another way of expressing the same:
            a /= 3.3

        tPoint = 100 - a * 0.00552

        # just another way of expressing the same:
        if 0 - (int(tPoint)) < a < (100 - (int(tPoint))):
            print("Liquid")

        if a < (0 - int(tPoint)):
            print("Solid")

        if a > (100 - int(tPoint)):
            print("Gas")
```

I hope this will help you. Please ask if something is still not clear.

Comment: Ok, I had just restructured my question before i saw your post. Thank you very much, this works great! Wow, you just saved my day man!

Comment: I really appreciate the detailed comments and breakdown. I am trying to learn python, so that is much appreciated.

Comment: One thing -- what exactly does 'finally' do again? You say *after* the exception occurs? Isn't the exception the error that we're catching?

Comment: See that [link](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) for a good explanation of `try … except … finally`. The finally here is only not executed, because of the sys.exit(). Don't give too much in that part of the code. I would recommend to refactor this part, anyway (as I mentioned).